# Wacom issues with the Fujitsu T4220 & T4210 Tablet PC

Tags: release-freya, system, touchpad, wacom

Could you guys take a look at the Wacom issues? On my Fujitsu T4220 & T4210 tablet PC the Wacom works great and the OS runs awesome; but when it comes back from sleep elementary OS says there is no tablet device, I have to reboot to see the Wacom tablet again. It is slightly annoying and has caused me to revert back to Ubuntu 12.04 which runs a LOT slower than elementary OS.

Comment: Does the device function properly on 14.04?

Comment: @Lewis so _elementary OS_ is based off _14.04_? does that mean this solution would work for _Elementary OS_? http://askubuntu.com/questions/511068/wacom-tablet-removed-after-sleep-mode

Comment: @Lewis After upgrading the tablet to 14.04 it wouldn't even come out of suspend, so I reinstalled 14.04 from scratch, but it took a few hours and runs so slow. it has the same issue as Elementary OS on ubuntu 14.04 but not on ubuntu 15. have they stopped support for 14.04 since 15 is out?

Comment: elementary uses Ubuntu 14.04 packages but Ubuntu 14.10 kernel, with an update to the 15.04 kernel coming soon. That might be the solution to your problem, although "wait" isn't a very good solution.

Comment: It doesn't matter, that issue worked on 14.04 but won't work on elementary apparently, another issue that is happening is that when it boots the screen is at normal rotation but once I log in it rotates to clockwise. ubuntu 14.04 doesn't do this, nor does ubuntu even recognize when I close my tablet screen face up and auto rotate the screen like Elementary does, good job on that feature.

Comment: No, Ubuntu 14.04 is supported for several years. Unfortunately, without the hardware myself it will be difficult to debug the issue.

Comment: Can you add the output of `lspci -k` while the tablet is connected